# Why isn't image_tag rendering my image in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I ahve the following image path

```
app/assets/images/loading_spinner.gif
```

I want to display this image on my page using the image_tag but neither

```
<% image_tag("images/loading_spinner.gif") %>
```

nor

```
<% image_tag("loading_spinner.gif") %>
```

displays any image tag on my page in my development environment.  How do I fix this?  I have tried restarting my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the equal:

```
<%= image_tag("loading_spinner.gif") %>
```